# find the correct end sequence for vim syntax region highlight

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a syntax file with:

```
syn region matlabLoop
            \ matchgroup=matlabRepeat
            \ start="\<for\>"
            \ end="\<end\>"
            \ transparent
            \ fold
hi def link matlabRepeat        Repeat
```

When I use this in a file I get the following (in matlab `end` has multiple uses. It can either end a loop/if/switch statement or be used as "the last entry in an array" (-1 in some other languages), so here `*end*` will be used to mark the highlighted word, note that the `*` symbols aren't in the program around an `end`)

```
a =  rand(1,3); % something like [0.0123145 1 0.545341]
for i = 1:numel(a)
    if numel(a(i:*end*)) ==numel(a)
        fprintf('i is probably 1')
    *end*
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work with just that single `matlabLoop` region. You need full parsing of the contained `if...end` structure as well; i.e. another syntax definition for the whole condition block. Or are you extending the existing `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/matlab.vim` syntax script (with folding)? The following assumes that (but the solution would apply to a standalone syntax definition just as well).

That syntax script defines a simple keyword for `end`, so it will match anywhere. If you want to exclude the `i:end` from matching, you need to make that match more precise, e.g. with a *negative lookbehind assertion* ("must not be preceded by a colon" - I don't know Matlab syntax, so this is just a suggestion on the technique, not the fully correct solution).

This is the original definition from the syntax script:

```
syn keyword matlabConditional       else elseif end if otherwise
```

In order to remove the `end`, we have to clear it and redefine:

```
syntax clear matlabConditional
syntax keyword matlabConditional else elseif if otherwise
```

Now we can specify the more precise specification, using [`:help /\@<!`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%21) for the assertion that there's no colon in front, and `\<...\>` to keep the keyword boundaries of the original definition:

```
syntax match matlabConditional ":\@<!\<end\>"
```

If you think this extension would be generally useful for the syntax, please submit a patch to the syntax script author; his contact information is in the header of that file.

Comment: I'm working on a new syntax file based on the version [1.2 of the matlab syntax](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=582) as this is a bit better than the one included in a vim install. I'm adding syntax folding, I'm having large troubles with wrong ends being detected as ends for these folds thou